# How to decode Scala compiler generated names

Tags: scala, name-mangling, scalac

Our code is killing the Scala compiler with this message:

```
[error] how can getCommonSuperclass() do its job if different class symbols
        get the same bytecode-level internal name: scala/Tuple2$mcJD$sp
```

To figure it out I'm trying to understand what `Tuple2$mcJD$sp` is supposed to be. Is it the class generated for `(Long, Double)`? Is this documented somewhere? Thanks!

---

Some clues I have found so far:

- I think the type abbreviations match those documented in [Class.getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).
- The name is generated in [SpecializeTypes.specializedName](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/SpecializeTypes.scala#L327). According to the code, the format is `m<abbreviated method specialization types>c<abbreviated class specialization types>$sp`.

Maybe it's considered a compiler internal thing and not documented anywhere.

Comment: is that an actual error from `scalac`?

Comment: The right term for this is [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

Comment: Yes, it's an actual error. The compiler dies with `AssertionError` Looks like the problem was that Kryo told me to register `Tuple2$mcJD$sp` and I did. I switched to registering `(Long, Double)` instead now, and it seems to avoid crashing `scalac`. I'll file a bug if I can create a minimal test case.